# Accessing cookie with Angular or Javascript

Tags: django, angularjs

I created an API /user/auth where I can send using POST a Json object like:

```
var user = {"username":"alex", "password":"m"}
$http(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/v1/user/auth',
                data: user,
            }
        ).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data)
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
```

The response from Django is the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type,*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Language:fr
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 30 Aug 2013 15:22:01 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
Set-Cookie:sessionid=w63m0aoo8m3vfmvv0vk5d6w1708ftsrk; Path=/
Vary:Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
```

So Django returns a good cookie but I don't know why, Chrome doesn't set this cookie in Resource.

The request is sent from 127.0.0.1:8000 to 127.0.0.1:8080; I use this [middleware](https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619) to handle CROS requests and I also set:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to Bqm link to mozilla I finally found why the cookie was not set.

Indeed you need to set in the header you sent:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

In Angular this is done with this method:

```
$http(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/v1/user/auth',
                data: user,
                withCredentials: true
            }
        )
```

Once your backend will answer with a setCookie, the browser will then be able to set the cookie in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line is:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The credential request doesn't work with a wildcard allow origin. You have to specifically set the name, like :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

You can find more information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: Sadly it is not working... I change the '*' to 127.0.0.1 and yet the cookie is not set :(